# PHP MySQL Table join - Echo identifier only once, then all matched items

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have a simple query that I need to modify but cant seem to figure out.

```
$query = "SELECT cust.first,pets.pet_name FROM `cust` 
    LEFT JOIN pets ON cust.id=pets.client_id 
    WHERE `clinic`='20'";
    $result = $conn->query($query) or die($conn->error.__LINE__);

    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $firstname=stripslashes($row['first']); 
            $pet=stripslashes($row['pet_name']);    
            echo $firstname." - ".$pet."<br/>";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'NO RESULTS';  
    }
```

This code produces:

```
Name1 - Pet 1
Name1 - Pet 2
Name2 - Pet 1
Name2 - Pet 2
Name3 - Pet 1
Name4 - Pet 1
```

What I need is:

```
Name1 - Pet 1, Pet 2
Name2 - Pet 1, Pet 2
Name3 - Pet 1
Name4 - Pet 1
```

But I cant find how to get this done.
I understand why its doing it incorrectly right now.

I have tried to concat the pets.pet_name as something, but cant get that to work.
What should I try next??

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to change the query to:

```
SELECT cust.first, GROUP_CONCAT(pets.pet_name) AS pet_names
FROM cust 
   LEFT JOIN pets ON cust.id=pets.client_id 
WHERE clinic = '20'
GROUP BY cust.id
```

It produces the result set you want; there is no need to change the PHP code.

Check the documentation of [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to see its options; by default it uses a comma (`','`) to join the values and maybe you want to have a space after the comma. You can also control the order of the values that are concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $curName = '';
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $firstname=stripslashes($row['first']); 
        $pet=stripslashes($row['pet_name']);    
        if ($firstname == $curName) {
          echo ",".$pet;
        } elseif ($curName!='') {
          echo "<br/>".$firstname." - ".$pet;
        } else {
          echo $firstname." - ".$pet;
        }
        $curName = $firstname;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea, logic to see if the name is the same.. I like it, BUT, can this not be handled by the sql query? If not, this is great, but I thought it could.

Comment: I think you can just add `ORDER BY cust.first ASC` or some other variant of GROUP or ORDER

Answer (score 0):

You should build an array like this:

```
array('data') {
    string ['cust_id'] => 
        ['firstname']=>string('Name1')
        array('pets') {
            [0]=> string('pet1')
            [1]=> string('pet2')
            [2]=> string('pet3')
             .
             .
             .
        }
}
```

This way, you have all pets that belong to a customer, the id_customer is the key. For this, you should fetch all your data to build it and then fetch it again to print.

Here is an example with no test:

```
$query = "SELECT cust.id, cust.first,pets.pet_name FROM `cust` 
    LEFT JOIN pets ON cust.id=pets.client_id 
    WHERE `clinic`='20'";
$result = $conn->query($query) or die($conn->error.__LINE__);

$data = array();
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $firstname=stripslashes($row['first']); 
        $pet=stripslashes($row['pet_name']);    
        echo $firstname." - ".$pet."<br/>";

        if(!isset($data[$row['cust.id']]['firstname']))
            $data[$row['cust.id']]['firstname'] = $firstname;
        $data[$row['cust.id']]['pets'][] = $pet;

    }
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $str = '';
        $str .= $item['firstname'];
        $num_pets = count($item['pets']);
        for($i=0;$i<$num_pets;$i++) {
            $str.= " - Pet " . $item['pets'][$i];
            if($i<($num_pets-1)) $str.=",";
        }
        echo $str ."<br/>";
    }
}
else {
    echo 'NO RESULTS';  
}
```